# After item value change and refresh Interactive grid, IG's query doesn't apply to changed value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Here is my item settings

item value : `P40_SET_MONTH`

item Type : `Month/Year Picker[Plug-in]`

.

Here is My Interactive Grid setting

```
SQL Query :

      select *
      from PROGRAM
      where to_char(CREATED, 'YYYY-MM') = :P40_SET_MONTH;
```

and I made DA to Item

When Item `value(P40_SET_MONTH)` changed, then refresh region that has Interactive Grid.

But even though after Refresh action is done,

Interactive Grid's Query doesn't accept the change item value.

ex. If Default `P40_SET_MONTH value is '2019-06',`

then after I changed item value into `'2019-05'`,

IG displays related to `'2019-06'` always.

In this case, how can I adjust changed item value to IG?

Comment: Firstly I would recommed having the same formats everywhere, to do a TO_DATE(:P40_SET_MONTH). Not sure if thats your problem, but its something to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IG region => Source => Page Items to Submit.

Put the item P40_SET_MONTH there

Hope it helps